# Unable to allocate GPU memory, when there is enough of cached memory

Tags: amazon-ec2, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I am training vgg16 model from scratch on *AWS EC2 Deep Learning AMI machine (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1054-aws x86_64v)) with Python3 (CUDA 10.1 and Intel MKL) (Pytorch 1.3.1)* and facing below error while updating model parameters.

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 24.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.76 GiB already allocated; 4.81 MiB free; 119.92 MiB cached)

Code for updating parameters:

```
def _update_fisher_params(self, current_ds, batch_size, num_batch):
    dl = DataLoader(current_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)
    log_liklihoods = []
    for i, (input, target) in enumerate(dl):
        if i > num_batch:
            break
        output = F.log_softmax(self.model(input.cuda().float()), dim=1)
        log_liklihoods.append(output[:, target])
    log_likelihood = torch.cat(log_liklihoods).mean()
    grad_log_liklihood = autograd.grad(log_likelihood, self.model.parameters())
    _buff_param_names = [param[0].replace('.', '__') for param in self.model.named_parameters()]
    for _buff_param_name, param in zip(_buff_param_names, grad_log_liklihood):
        self.model.register_buffer(_buff_param_name+'_estimated_fisher', param.data.clone() ** 2)
```

After debugging: `log_liklihoods.append(output[:, target])` line throws error after 157 iterations

I have the required memory but it does not allocate, I am not getting why updating the gradients is causing the memory problem, as gradients should be de-referenced and released automatically on each iteration. Any idea?

I have tried following solutions but no luck.

- Lowering batch size
- Freeing cache with torch.cuda.empty_cache()
- Reducing the number of filters to reduce the memory footprint

**Machine Specs:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved the memory problem! I realized that in each iteration I put the input data in a new tensor, and pytorch generates a new computation graph. 
That causes the used RAM to grow forever. Then I used .detach() function, and the RAM always stays at a low level.

```
self.model(input.cuda().float()).detach().requires_grad_(True)
```